# Wierd gray line when trying to hide browsing button

Tags: html, css

CONTEXT : I got a browse button (`<input type="file"/>`) and a custom button. I linked the click event of my custom button to the click event of the browse button, which work so far. Now I only need to hide the original textbox of the input.

But here is my problem : when I try to hide the control, there is a weird gray lane that stay. I tried many ways to make it disappear, but it appear to be a weird bug since it awkwardly appear on the control before I hide it. Here is the control before I try to hide it :

[image]

and after:

[image]

So far I tried : 
-Set css property top: -10000px, visibility: hidden, opacity: 0, width: 0px, etc

Does anyone had this bug/problem before?

Comment: can share your demo link?

Comment: @pptaszek1990 Tried it, doesn't work =(. Here is the fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/zwaefdfh/1/

Comment: `<input type:"file"/>` is not valid HTML...

Comment: @Sverri M. Olsen Mixed with css, fixed.

Comment: jQuery Mobile is doing it.

Comment: Yep, `.ui-input-text, .ui-input-search` simply has a 1px border defined.

Comment: Can I remove it? I tried border: 0px, still appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, with all the commentary, I ended up finding the solution.

HTML:

```
<div class="relative-content">
            <input class="inputToCover" id="file" type="file"/>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.inputToCover 
{
    visibility: hidden;
}

.ui-input-text
{
    border: 0px;
    box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

Thanks a lot everyone for the fast answers.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is coming from the jquery mobile css:

```
.ui-body-a, .ui-page-theme-a .ui-body-inherit, html .ui-bar-a .ui-body-        inherit, html .ui-body-a .ui-body-inherit, html body .ui-group-theme-a .ui-body-inherit, html .ui-panel-page-container-a {
background-color: #fff;
border-color: #ddd;
color: #333;
text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #f3f3f3;
   }
```

The border is giving you the issue.

Do something like:

```
.ui-body-a, .ui-page-theme-a .ui-body-inherit, html .ui-bar-a .ui-body-inherit, html .ui-body-a .ui-body-inherit, html body .ui-group-theme-a .ui-body-inherit, html .ui-panel-page-container-a { border: none; }
```

That should fix your issue.

Comment: Yeah I did, parents doesn't have border properties that could have affected this control.

Comment: Can you throw the code into a fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/) and ill take a look at it? Also, is it in any browser you get the issue, or only one?

Comment: I linked the fiddle in the main commentary and im using IE10 (no choice...)

Comment: Looks like your issue is coming from a style in jquery mobile.

Comment: .ui-body-a, .ui-page-theme-a .ui-body-inherit, html .ui-bar-a .ui-body-inherit, html .ui-body-a .ui-body-inherit, html body .ui-group-theme-a .ui-body-inherit, html .ui-panel-page-container-a {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-color: #ddd;
    color: #333;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #f3f3f3;
    }

Comment: Updated the answer to reflect this.